# Can't pass array from react to django

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I m trying to get an array from react frontend (stored in local storage) to my view class in django but i'm getting this error:

**In console:**

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/quiz/multiple/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**Django LOGS:**

```
    for quiz in quizzes:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
ERROR:django.server:"GET /api/quiz/multiple/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20064
```

Here's how i store the data in the LocalStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('quizzes', JSON.stringify(quizList));
        history.push('/start')
```

And here's how i get it from local storage and pass it to the django using axios:

```
export default function QuizPage() {

    const [DataState,setDataState] = useState([]);
    const storedQuizzes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("quizzes"))
    useEffect(() => {
          axiosInstance
          .get(`quiz/multiple/`, {
            quizzes: storedQuizzes
        }).then((res) => {
                setDataState(res.data);
            })
            .catch((function (error) {
            console.log(error)
    }));
    }, [setDataState]);
```

and, finally, that's my django view:

```
class MultipleQuizView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self,request):
        questionsList = []
        quizzes = request.data.get('quizzes')
        for quiz in quizzes:
            currentQuiz = Quiz.objects.get(url=quiz)
            quizSerializer = QuizSerializerForMultipleQuizzes(currentQuiz)
            question = Question.objects.filter(quiz__url=quiz)
            questionSerializer = QuestionSerializer(question, many=True)
            quizSerializerData = quizSerializer.data.copy()
            quizSerializerData["questions"]=questionSerializer.data
            questionsList.append(quizSerializerData)
        if questionsList:
            return Response(questionsList)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'm pretty sure the problem isn't from my view class because i tested it using Postman and it works without any problem.

**EDIT**:

I just tryed with postman using this body and it works properly:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RJ5A.png

So i need to send data from react like this but i don't know how:

```
{
    "quizzes":["securitate","aparare"]
}
```

Comment: If it helps, i used console.log(storedQuizzes) and that's what it says: ```(2) ["protectie", "aparare"]```

Comment: core urls: ```path('api/quiz/', include('quiz.urls',namespace='quiz')),``` and quiz.urls: ```path('multiple/', MultipleQuizView.as_view(),name='multiple')```

Comment: Check browser devtools network tab that the request is as expected compared to Postman.  You should edit your question to include the info you provided in comments.

Comment: @James i tried but i can t see the content of "quizzes" sent with the request :( https://ibb.co/nP6HxV3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

The problem was that i wrote:

```
quizzes = request.data('quizzes')
```

instead of:

```
quizzes = request.data['quizzes']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second param to axios.get as follows:

```
axiosInstance
  .get(`quiz/multiple/`, {
    params: {
      quizzes: storedQuizzes
    }
  }).then(...)
```

[Read more](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) about the properties that the second param supports.

Comment: now i got ```GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/quiz/multiple/?quizzes[]=protectie&quizzes[]=aparare 500 (Internal Server Error)```

Comment: Great, so you are now sending the data, even though the server is still struggling.  I don't know what format your web server expects the array to be in for get requests?  You can likely use the paramsSerializer property to provide a transformation function.

Comment: that's how i should receive data in django: ```{ "quizzes":["securitate","aparare"] }``` i tested it with postman and it works properly..the problem is that when i send data from react like this ```Array [ "rezilienta", "aparare" ]
​
0: "rezilienta"
​
1: "aparare"
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []``` in django i got: ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
``` and i really don t know why..